# Data Factory - Use wildcard to determine filename

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I'm using Data Factory in a way to move a file from my file system to a Blob Storage.

The problem is: the file is named using YYYYMMDD identifiers, [which I could resolve by partitioning ({year}{month}{day})] AND TIME (that is the file creation time).

How do I get the filename having the dynamic time in it? I already tried using *, _ and other usual wildcards.

I will really appreciate your help!

Comment: The filename is something like this: FILENAME_20171221034566.txt

Comment: I have already tried to use filefilter property, that doesn't work on Blob Storage and "Starts with" (set on the filepath property) but it tries to find a folder instead of filtering the files. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ADFv1 the combinations of file filter, file name and file path are really limited and the wild cards don't work together across the different attributes.

Given your situation I think there isn't currently anything you'll be able to do about this.

Best options I can suggest:

1. Get the year month and day created as parent folders in the location where the source data comes from.
2. Ignore the file name totally. Then use a custom activity shred the file names with some C# in a downstream activity.

I done option 2 in the past as changing source systems isn't always an option.

I appreciate neither of these options are ideal. **Option 3** would be to do something more dynamically within an ADFv2 activity using expressions for the file path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I chose Option 3 even before you answer. I can tell you that is the best option ever.

I have also worked with folders named as date , ignoring the filename. It looks like that mostly all of your suggestion matched with my choices.

Thanks a lot for the answer!